# how to insert into table dependent on other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one call users and the other called todolist. In my web app I have an admin function that I would like to have the admin be able to assign a to do to all the user. I'm trying to write the SQL but I'm just seem to be hitting writiers block or I'm just plain dumb.

So how can I select all the users from the users table and then do an insert to the todo table so that basically the todo table ends up with each user and a task?

Comment: Perhaps - INSERT INTO TODO(USERID, TASK) SELECT(USERID, 'SomeTask') FROM USERS

Comment: very helpful but what if i wanted to select the max id on the todo list before actually inserting? i keep getting an error if i try this. 'INSERT INTO todo (field1, field2, field3, ...) SELECT max(somfield) somefield1, somefield2, somefield3, ... FROM users,todo '

Comment: That would be a mistake - Max(somefield) might give two users the same result if they tried the operation simultaneously.  It would better if you used a Sequence which is guaranteed unque.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`INSERT ... SELECT FROM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO todo (field1, field2, field3, ...)
SELECT somefield1, somefield2, somefield3, ...
FROM users
WHERE ...
```

Comment: thanks Marc B just one more question. What if i want to select the max mumber from the table im going to insert and have that as part of my insert how woulld i go about doing something like that? in other word `INSERT INTO todo (field1, field2, field3, ...) SELECT max(somfield) somefield1, somefield2, somefield3, ... FROM users,todo WHERE ...` Is this correct it seems to fail for me.

Comment: using an aggregate function (like max) along with other non-aggregated fields requires using a `group by` clause.